# Broken Wordpress Admin

Tags: wordpress

I have a client who has asked me to start working on their Wordpress site. The admin page is broken and I do not have access to the database yet (I am trying to track down the previous people who worked on it). It is quite messy, I know.

What I am doing now is migrating peices over to a new wordpress site using Wamp server just to get it functional, but I am wondering if the solution is simpler than that. Ideally, I would just fix the the login, but I have minimal Wordpress experience and don't know where to start.

Here is the website: http://fundafighter.com

If you go to http://fundafighter.com/wp-admin you'll notice that it is broken. I reroutes to "login-2", which I don't think is normal. So far I haven't found any folder with that title...

Answer (score 0):

I would log into the site via FTP, check the wp-config.php file for any redirects for wp-login.php. Then, check the .htaccess file for the same. Remove any references.

If you get that page working, and you need to reset the password, I would follow this tutorial through phpMyAdmin:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Resetting_Your_Password#Through_phpMyAdmin